# Target namespace java util cxf and code generation package java.util.xsd

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, cxf

I have propieratary schema using target namespace

xmlns:ax216="http://util.java/xsd"

This gives me a problem with generating prohibited (by Java Security Manager) packages in starting with java (java.util.xsd).Refactoring classes is not enough. I still get an error from security manager. Service authors use axis2 but mixing this two libraries is not allowed in eclipse. Do you have any idea how to consume this service with CXF?

Event though I map them to different package I still have an exception:

```
   Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Prohibited package name: java.util.logging.xsd
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:156)
        at $Proxy34.getBandwidthInformation(Unknown Source)
        at com.adva.internal.measurement.gen.MeasurementModuleInterfaceImpl.main(FancyModuleInterfaceImpl.java:64)
   Caused by: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Prohibited package name: java.util.logging.xsd
```

Comment: Is your question unable to consume service with CXF or generating packages with http://util.java/xsd?

Comment: It looks like choosing CXF forces way of generating by wsdl2java different packages than AXIS. The CXF ones are in forbidden namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wsdl2java tool has a -p flag to map namespaces.

```
wsdl2java -p http://util.java/xsd=com.foo.blah  mywsdl.wsdl
```

should do it.

Comment: My previous comment is an eclipse caused problem.